# Finding a good cover of $\mathbb{P}^2_k$ with respect to the constant sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, sheaf-cohomology

$\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}_k}$
$\newcommand{\A}{\mathbb{A}_k}$
I am trying to find another way of showing that $\P^2$ is not homeomorphic to $\A^2$... namely I am trying to show that the cohomologies with respect to the constant sheaf is zero.

The usual cover $U_0,U_1,U_2$ is not a good cover... the cohomology is concentrated in degree zero with respect to this cover.  ( If you look in the $\P^1$ when $k=\mathbb{C}$ case you see that $U_0 \cap U_1$ has nontrivial cohomology with respect to the constant sheaf. Hence this is why the cohomology ends up being zero).

Question:  What is a good cover for $\P^2$?

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about in the case $k=\mathbb{C}$...maybe you're talking about the Euclidean topology rather than the Zariski topology?  That changes the question dramatically...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any constant sheaf on an irreducible topological space is flasque.  Specifically, if $\mathcal{F}$ is the sheaf of locally constant maps to a set $A$ on a space $X$, then $\mathcal{F}(U)$ consists of just the constant maps if $U$ is a connected open set.  But if $X$ is irreducible, every open subset is connected, and so $\mathcal{F}(U)$ is just the constant maps for all $U$.  It follows that all the restriction maps $\mathcal{F}(U)\to\mathcal{F}(V)$ are bijections (unless $V$ is empty), and $\mathcal{F}$ is flasque.

In particular, if $A$ is an abelian group, the cohomlogy of $\mathcal{F}$ will be trivial in positive degrees.  This applies both to $X=\mathbb{A}^2_k$ and $X=\mathbb{P}^2_k$, and so cannot be used to distinguish them topologically.

Comment: thanks! this clears a lot of my confusion about why the cohomologies were becoming zero.